# How to define norm on semi vector spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

And and can we give proofs different from vector space norm proofs with its restriction?Can we give standard proofs with the lack of additive identity and additive inverse property?

Answer (score 0):

No in general. For instance, the gliding hump proof of the uniform boundedness principle fails horribly. Also, the Hahn-Banach theorem can't be proven in the usual way because we can't pass to zero or to a subspace.

The strategy to obtain results would be to embed the semi vector space into some vector space. This works e.g. when the semi vector space has some sort of "basis".

Comment: Thnx can u give me some more properties..

Comment: It would help greatly if you had a particular semi vector space in mind...

Comment: If you, for instance, were to talk about a convex cone in a Hilbert space, then things would work fine...

Comment: Can it work with 0 included and defining inner product  on it and can we get different proofs  ..i am specific abt the semi field of positive real numbers can u give me some simple semi vector spaces so that i can try to bring its norm properties

Comment: Possibly one could formally define the extension to the real numbers as a positive and negative part, just like the Grothendieck group construction. In this case, one would have an embedding and could get the results one wants from that.